# Найти количество повторяющихся элементов

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

[image: вот, что выходит]

Сначала сортирую массив, чтобы расставить элементы в порядке возрастания. потом пытаюсь посчитать количество повторяющихся элементов, но не выходит.

```
int min, k = 1;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    min = mas[0];
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (mas[i]>mas[j])
        {
            min = mas[j];
            mas[j] = mas[i];
            mas[i] = min;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (mas[i] != mas[j])
            continue;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для каких целей нужно искать и считать повторения? Они нужны? Если нет, лучше будет воспользоваться arrayUnique - удалит все дубликаты и вернет новый размер массива.

Comment: ... например, посчитать количество букв "л" в слове "колличество".

Comment: решаю задачи с массивами в качестве тренировки и подготовки к экзамену. только недавно начала изучать с++. по условию, пользоваться arrayUnique нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порой введение дополнительного внутреннего цикла упрощает логику вычисления.:)

Если вам нужно подсчитать общее количество повторяющихся элементов, то программа с использованием вашего подхода может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] < a[i])
            {
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t n = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (++i < N && a[i] == a[i - 1]) ++j;
        if (j != 0) n += j + 1;
    }

    std::cout << "There are " << n << " repeated elements" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 2 2 4 1 0 0 0 1 2
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 4
There are 9 repeated elements
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну, отсортировали вы без проблем, но раз уж массив отсортирован - то просто проходите по нему, сравнивая каждый с предыдущим:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (mas[i] == mas[i-1]) ++k;
}
cout << k << endl;
```

Здесь я не учитываю первые элементы серий, считая их неповторяющимися, т.е. в массиве, скажем
`0`  *`0`*  `2`  `4`  *`4`* *`4`* *`4`* `5` *`5`*  *`5`*
считается, что есть 6 повторяющихся элементов (выделены курсивом).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    min = mas[0];
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (mas[i]>mas[j])
        {
            min = mas[j];
            mas[j] = mas[i];
            mas[i] = min;
        }
    }
}

int k = 0; // counter
int last = -1;
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
  if(mas[i] == mas[i+1]){

    if(last == mas[i]){
      k++;
    }else{
      last = mas[i];
      k += 2;
    }

  }
}
```

ну типа того, сам не тестил, но должно работать, в любом случае идею надеюсь уловили.

Answer (score 0):

Считаем количество уникальных:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename Compare = std::equal_to<>>
auto count_unique(InputIt first, InputIt last, Compare cmp = {}) {
  assert(std::is_sorted(first, last));
  typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type result = 0;
  while (first != last) {
    ++result;
    auto group_first = first;
    do {
      ++first;
    } while (first != last && cmp(*group_first, *first));
  }
  return result;
}
```

И вычитаем их из общего количества элементов:

```
size(mas) - count_unique(std::begin(mas), std::end(mas));
```